# Misleading day count in profile

Tags: support, stack-overflow, profile-page, consecutive-days, visited-days

Below is a screenshot of my profile page on Stack Overflow.

[image: My profile page]

Here, it says, visited "5 consecutive" days, which I believe is the number of days I had visited the site continuously. But, the graph shows 11 days.

Please correct me if I'm wrong and what does "5 consecutive" mean?

Comment: Does Sunday not count anymore?

Comment: @animuson Well, i didn't know that. If Sunday is counted as a break, that is correct obviously. But, that does not make sense. Do you not visit SO on sundays or work on sundays?

Comment: *You* obviously don't, according to that calendar, which is why you only have 5 consecutive days. Monday to friday. animuson's comment was probably meant to be somewhat... rhetorical. =)

Comment: @J.Steen I am not going to argue here, but i **do** login everyday. So, irrespective of the timezone, it should display that. Because, in my timezone, i log in to SO at least once/day(that's an understatement ;))

Comment: Your profile summary disagrees, I'm afraid. If you feel that the bug is really "I've logged in on day x, but it didn't count", then state **that** instead. There's nothing wrong in the consecutive count itself as is obvious by your own screenshot. =)

Comment: [We visit SE even on holidays!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Y6Y.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have mistaken.There is nothing **Misleading** in this as you think, the reason is actually you had **misunderstood**.  Its clearly visible in your Question itself.

February 10 sunday is not marked as visited in the calendar . If you are not well aware of what the term consecutive means, please see [con·sec·u·tive](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=cinsecutive%20meaning&oq=cinsecutive%20meaning&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) here.

If you had ignored that Sunday by mistake, it can be excused.Sometimes mistakes happen.

If its not so , I just want to make you aware that here we count Sundays too, its not a holiday for SO. 
Hope this helps you.

Comment: What was i thinking. Friday effects, for sure :)

Comment: Well... that's quite a [rude](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rude) answer. -1

Comment: Clearly, the OP thought consecutively meant something else. Perhaps being in India and, presumably, not having English as his first language contributed to that. Being rude is not excused here, or pretty much ever. Although your answer is correct, I can't bring myself to upvote it due to its tone.

Comment: @AndrewBarber well, that makes sense..just made an edit..do you think its still rude?

Comment: Not as blatantly rude. But still not polite.

Comment: @AndrewBarber well, that too makes sense..again made an edit..do you  still think its rude?

Comment: That's better. I see that you, yourself, are from India, too!

Comment: @AndrewBarber sure...but how does that matter here? SO is not a site for a particular locality.Its quite global.

Comment: Because I can *guess* that perhaps English is also not your first language, and perhaps you don't fully see how your wording might not be as polite as it could be.

Comment: @AndrewBarber oh, agreed. Didn't you notice that I made all these edits as per your suggestion! Its just because I need to get myself corrected if the way my answer sounds is not acceptable here.

Comment: @DuncanJones the tone has totally changed now :-) Have a look

Answer (score 6):

> Because, in my timezone, i log in to SO at least once/day(that's an understatement ;)

All dates and references to days in SO/SE are calculated according to UTC time. It could be that if you are logging in, say, first thing **local time** in the morning on Wednesday, and last thing **local time** at night on Thursday, that there is an entire UTC day missing in the middle.

Comment: +1. Finally something that i think could be the cause. Thank you.